# Visual Studio: How to make one project build AFTER others?

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible to build a project B each time after the build of another project A in the same solution?

I tried to solve it with build dependencies and references, but it seems only possible to make the build B BEFORE the build of A another project.

(reason why I want to do it: execute a common post build process from project B).
(Visual Studio 2013)